# How to Display Status Description for a 403 error in ASP.net MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm attempting to create custom 403 error page that will display the **status description** from the error.

I'm using the following code to trigger the 403 error

from both Controllers and Action Filters

**Controller Call**

```
 return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
                                "String_Of_Why_This_Request_is_Forbiden")
```

**Actionfilter Call**

```
 filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
                                "String_Of_Why_This_Request_is_Forbiden")
```

Both of these get redirected to my Custom 403 error page.

but as the request passes through my Web config and errors controller I lose both the *HTTP status code* and the *status description*.

**Web.Config**

```html
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
  <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="0" />
  <error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="0" path="/Error/Forbidden" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

**ErrorControllerAction**

```
   public ViewResult Forbidden(string errorMessage)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 403;
        return View("Forbidden", errorMessage);
    }
```

My assumption is that my current handling is simply generating a new request via my errors controller.

**Question**

How can I do this in such a way that I can pass the Original Status Description through the Errors Controller to my View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can redirect to you controller action and pass in the error message instead.

Comment: I can but I my preference is to handle via HTTP errors such that other dependencies work like logging.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good general article for custom error page in ASP.NET MVC

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/618722/custom-error-page-in-Asp-Net-mvc/